# Why is this JNI function not printing until the application terminates?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Just getting started with JNI, and not sure why the log messages in C don't post to the terminal until after the app terminates.

```
public static native long initialize(String arg);
public static native boolean hasImage();
public static native void dispose();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long id = ClipboardHelper.initialize("");
    System.out.println(id);

    try {
        System.in.read(); //wait for enter key
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    ClipboardHelper.dispose();
}
```

C code:

```c
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_mypackage_ClipboardHelper_initialize
(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jstring arg) {
    printf("hello world");
    return 1;
}
```

When I run the app, I see it print 1 from the Java `println` method call:

`1`

But it doesn't print `hello world` until I hit the enter key to continue the app.

```
1
hello world
```

I can see that the C function returned, because the correct number was printed in Java. In fact, I can call several native methods and only after I press enter do all the queued up `printf` message appear.

Comment: `printf` is line buffered by default. So it won't actually flush to stdout until a newline is encountered. Or an explicit flush (which does happen on app exit). So either end the printf string with a `\n` or explicitly call `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: Thanks. I was assuming I was running into a JNI oddity. :/